# Slice array of tuples by its elements

Tags: python, arrays, list, tuples

For example, I have an array of tuples.

```
l=[(456,33,1),
   (556,22,1),
   (123,33,2),
   (557,32,2),
   (435,21,2)]
```

I want make the arrays of lists by the last element in each tuple, so that

```
l=[[(456,33),
   (556,22)],
  [(123,33),
   (557,32),
   (435,21)]]
```

How could I do that? Is there any elegant way?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the list already sorted based on the third entry of the tuples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
l = [(456, 33, 1), (556, 22, 1), (123, 33, 2), (557, 32, 2), (435, 21, 2)]

out = {}
for v in l:
    out.setdefault(v[-1], []).append(v[:-1])

out = list(out.values())
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[[(456, 33), (556, 22)], 
 [(123, 33), (557, 32), (435, 21)]]
```

Comment: depending on the python implementation the OP is using and their needs, they might run into problems with the order in which the elements in `out` appear (which might be out of sync with `l`). Otherwise I find this solution super elegant. +1

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this would be with `itertools.groupby`.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

res = [[x[:-1] for x in g] for _, g in groupby(sorted(l, key=itemgetter(2)), itemgetter(2))]
```

which produces the desired:

```
[[(456, 33), (556, 22)], [(123, 33), (557, 32), (435, 21)]]
```

Note that if you can guarantee that the original list `l` is sorted by the 3rd item in the tuples, you can replace `sorted(l, key=itemgetter(2))` with just `l`.

Comment: Note also that there's no need to create the full list of lists if all you want to do is iterate over the resulting sequence.  In that case, this reduces to `for key, group in groupby(l, key=itemgetter(2))` where `key` will be the third entry of the original tuple and `group` will be an iterator over all of the tuples with `key` as the third entry.

Comment: @Brian sure. I will however leave that to the OP to decide.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative attempt is using this:

```
l=[(456,33,1),
   (556,22,1),
   (123,33,2),
   (557,32,2),
   (435,21,2)]
   
dict_ = {}
for v in l:
  val1, val2, id_ = v
  dict_[id_] = [[val1, val2]] if id_ not in dict_ else dict_[id_] + [[val1, val2]]
    
l = [dict_[x] for x in dict_]
```